# How to integrate $\int_{0}^{2} \sqrt{x+\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x+\cdots}}}\,dx$?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I want to integrate this $$\int_{0}^{2} \sqrt{x+\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x+\cdots}}}\,dx$$

I tried making the substitution $u^2=x+u$ and  my integral turns into

$$\int_{0}^{2}u(2u-1)\,du = \frac{10}{3}$$

However the answer is supposed to be $\dfrac{19}{6}$, I would like to know where I am making a mistake or another way

Comment: The function $x \mapsto u(x) = \sqrt{x + \sqrt{x + \cdots}}$ is discontinuous at $x = 0$, you should replace the lower limit of $u$ integration from $u(0) = 0$ to $\lim_{x\to 0+}u(x) = 1$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your approach is fine. Just note that $x(u)=u^2-u$ maps $[1,2]$ onto $[0,2]$, and therefore, after the substitution, the lower limit of integration is $1$. Hence
$$\int_{0}^{2} \sqrt{x+\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x+\cdots}}}dx=\int_{1}^{2}u(2u-1)du=\frac{19}{6}.$$

Comment: How do you know these new limits ?

Comment: $x=u^2-u$ maps $[1,2]$ onto $[0,2]$

Comment: What about $[-1,0]$, which also is mapped into $[0,2]$ ?

Comment: @JaroslawMatlak $u=\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x+\cdots}}}$ should be non-negative.

Answer (score 7):

Let $L(x)=\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x+\cdots}}$.

$L(x)^2=x+L(x)$, hence, $L(x)^2-L(x)-x=0$ and $L(x)=\frac{1\pm\sqrt{1+4x}}{2}$.

Because $L(x)\ge0$, $L(x)=\frac{1+\sqrt{1+4x}}{2}$ and then the intergal is straightforward.

Answer (score -1):

### Hint:

solve the two equations to find the new limits of integration( use the $u^2-u=x$)
$$u^2-u=0$$
and
$$u^2-u=2$$

Comment: This does not provide any guidance on which solution one should pick for $u$ in either case. The OP picked solutions that satisfy these equations - this hint doesn't have much in it.

Comment: Actually, he points the OP to the limits of integration, which is where the error was.  You are being a bit harsh on E.H.E.